# How d[key] is getting values of python dictionary in iteration(for loop)

Tags: python, python-3.x

How `d[key]` is getting dictionary values in for loop? I know the other way to write dictionary code in for loop is:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3} 
for key, values in d.items():
    print (key, 'corresponds to', values)
```

But I want to know how in below for loop how `d[key]` is getting values. Is there dictionary values are getting convert to list? Please help me here.

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3} 
for key in d:
    print (key, 'corresponds to', d[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

When you simply iterate over a `dict` like that, you are actually iterating over the keys of the dictionary. For example:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> list(d)
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Then, `d[key]` accesses the value at the specified key in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

It' because in the second snippet you are accessing directly the dict (`d[key]`):

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3} 
for key in d:
  print(key) # <-- see the output
  print (key, 'corresponds to', d[key])
```

`d.items()` is a kind of helper which returns the pair key, value:

```
print(d.items()) #=> dict_items([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)])
```

Something like:

```
lst = [(1,2), (2,4)]
for k,v in lst:
  print(k, v)
```

Comment: I have another question, in a list x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,4,3,2,1] how can I get second in last record of 4 using loop.

Comment: @TARUN PUNETHA, I think I don’t completely understand your question.

Comment: thanks for help earlier, I was asking to remove duplicates from a list. Sorry for confusion.I searched in stack overflow and I got answer, using set() function duplicates can be removed.